# Least Squares Definition in Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: self-study, least-squares, matrix

In *Elements of Statistical Learning*, they state on p. 11 that all vectors are column vectors and start developing the least squares idea.

So if we have
$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
\vdots \\
X_p\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\beta}_0 \\
\hat{\beta}_1 \\
\vdots \\
\hat{\beta}_p
\end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$
take $$\hat{Y} = \mathbf{X}^{T}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \langle \mathbf{X}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \rangle\text{.}$$
So $\hat{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^1$ because $\mathbf{X}^{T} \in M_{1 \times p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta} \in M_{p \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$. Fine.

Now they say:

> ... in general $\hat{Y}$ can be a $K$-vector, in which case $\beta$ (I
>   think this is a typo - they should probably have $\hat{\beta}$ instead) would be a $p \times K$ matrix of coefficients.

Well, here's the problem. If $\mathbf{X}^{T} \in M_{1 \times p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{\beta} \in M_{p \times K}(\mathbb{R})$, wouldn't $\mathbf{X}^{T}\hat{\beta}$ give a *row vector* for $\mathbf{Y}$ (dimensions $1 \times K$)?

Comment: Your $X$ makes no sense in this context unless its elements are interpreted as *row* vectors of dimension $K$.  Both $\beta$ and its estimate $\hat\beta$ are column vectors of dimension $p+1$, as you show.  Have you perhaps mixed up the roles of $X$ and $\beta$ in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you confuse yourself a bit. In page 10 the authors say:

*"a set of $N$ input $p$-vectors $x_i$ , $i = 1, \dots, N$ would be represented by the $N \times p$ matrix **$X$**."*

This means that the $p$ feature vectors/regressors they use will be represented as column vectors in the matrix $X$. For that matter and to quote from the text page 12 exactly :

*"$X$ is an $N \times p$ matrix with each row an input vector"*.

So $X^T$ is not a row (or column) vector in any case. $X$ (and its transpose) will be (probably) of rank $p$. $\hat{Y}$ will be a matrix $N \times K$. For the case of OLS model $K$ is usually equal to unity (1) but this is not a strict prerequisite for its use (that's why usually we write $\hat{y}$).